# How to sort data according to the status in mongoose aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have many records in a commission collection.

```
{
    "_id": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf7", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-06T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena", 
    "status": "Created", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2b996d8082a30d27581cf9",
    "createdAt": "2020-08-05T05:34:08.281Z", 
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Pending", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2ba2e28082a30d27581cfe", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-05T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Accepted", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},

{
    "_id": "5f2ba2ea8082a30d27581cff", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-04T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Pending", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2ba2ea8082a30d27581cff", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-03T03:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Rejected", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
}
```

I need to sort by Pending status and createdAt in desc(I mean all pending records on the top with the createdAt Date desc order)

status = `Created , Pending, Accepted, Rejected`;

It should be like this

```
{
    "_id": "5f2b996d8082a30d27581cf9",
    "createdAt": "2020-08-05T05:34:08.281Z", 
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Pending", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2ba2ea8082a30d27581cff", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-04T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Pending", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf7", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-06T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena", 
    "status": "Created", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2ba2e28082a30d27581cfe", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-05T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Accepted", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
},
{
    "_id": "5f2ba2ea8082a30d27581cff", 
    "createdAt": "2020-08-03T05:34:08.281Z",
    "supplierName": "John Cena",
    "status": "Rejected", 
    "commissionID": "5f2b96508082a30d27581cf6"
}
```

I am using mongodb 3.4, mongoose and node.js.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with custom ordering.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Rc_7kuz3Ay)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sortId: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [ //If pending
              "$status",
              "Pending"
            ]
          },
          0, //then 0
          {
            $cond: [
              { //Else if created
                $eq: [
                  "$status", 
                  "Created"
                ]
              },
              1, //then 1
              2 //Else 2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortId: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gibbs